# How to download multiple files store in root and subfolder together in Blob Storage Container using JAVA?

Tags: java, azure, azure-devops, azure-blob-storage

Currently I want to download all the files I store inside my blob storage container, and below is my code for download the file.

```
    CloudBlobContainer cloudBlobContainer = StorageAccount(azureStorageProperties,clientCredential).createCloudBlobClient()
            .getContainerReference(container);

        System.out.println("Access " + container + " container successful. Now start to download the file.");
        Iterable<ListBlobItem> blobs = cloudBlobContainer.listBlobs();

        for (ListBlobItem blob : blobs) {

            CloudBlockBlob cloudBlob = (CloudBlockBlob) blob;
            cloudBlob.downloadToFile(inputPath + "/" + cloudBlob.getName());
        }
```

However, I'm facing an issue when I try to download, the console show me below error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlobDirectory cannot be cast to class com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.CloudBlockBlob
```

[This is the dump screen of my blob storage container. Please take a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iTdO0.png)

Please help me how can I download all the files inside root and subfolder without having this error. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe these codes can give you some inspiration:

```
package org.example;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.CloudStorageAccount;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.ResultSegment;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.StorageException;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.blob.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.URISyntaxException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;

public class App 
{
    public static final String storageConnectionString = "";
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        String inputPath = "";
        try {
            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.parse(storageConnectionString);
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.createCloudBlobClient();
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.getContainerReference("");
            Iterable<ListBlobItem> blobs = container.listBlobs();
            for (ListBlobItem blob : container.listBlobs()) {
                System.out.println("URI of blob is: " + blob.getUri());
                if (blob.getUri().toString().endsWith("/")){
                    String[] arr = blob.getUri().toString().split("/");
                    String directoryname = arr[arr.length-1];
                    CloudBlobDirectory directory = container.getDirectoryReference(directoryname);
                    downloadFile(directory,inputPath);
                }else {
                    CloudBlockBlob cloudBlob = (CloudBlockBlob) blob;
                    File file = new File(inputPath + "\\" + cloudBlob.getName());
                    file.mkdirs();
                    cloudBlob.downloadToFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (StorageException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private static void downloadFile(CloudBlobDirectory directory, String inputPath){
        try {
            for (ListBlobItem blob : directory.listBlobs()) {
                System.out.println("URI of blob is: " + blob.getUri());
                if (blob.getUri().toString().endsWith("/")){
                    String[] arr = blob.getUri().toString().split("/");
                    String directoryname = arr[arr.length-1];
                    CloudBlobDirectory directory1 = directory.getDirectoryReference(directoryname);
                    downloadFile(directory1,inputPath);
                }else {
                    CloudBlockBlob cloudBlob = (CloudBlockBlob) blob;
                    File file = new File(inputPath + "\\" + cloudBlob.getName());
                    file.mkdirs();
                    cloudBlob.downloadToFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
                }
            }
        } catch (StorageException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow!!! This is exactly what I'm looking for!! Thanks Frank!! Really save me a lot of time to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already come across this, refer [How to upload and download blobs from Azure Blob Storage with Java](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/azure-sdk-for-java-storage-blob-upload-download/upload-download-blobs-java/)

use [Azure Storage samples using v12 Java client libraries](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/blob/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-file-share/src/samples/java/com/azure/storage/file/share/FileSample.java#L100) to Download files.

> The storage of azure blob storage is actually flat, it actually has no so-called folders at all.
> You have to combine the path and file name as the filename passing method. If you list the files in the current container, you will find that they are in a form similar to this:

```
 folder1/folder2/filename.suffix


 // Download storage file to local file.
    String downloadPath = filePath + "testfiles/" + "downloadSample.txt";
    File downloadFile = new File(downloadPath);
    try {
        if (!Files.exists(downloadFile.toPath()) && !downloadFile.createNewFile()) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create new upload file.");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create new upload file.");
    }
```